# How to make a FULLTEXT search with ORDER BY fast?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-5.6, full-text-search

I'm trying to get a simple FULLTEXT match to be faster when using order by on another column on a table with over 100 million rows. The basis is one table with a fulltext on two columns and I want to search the database but order it by either the primary (least/most recent) or popularity. Is it possible to make a FULLTEXT with an order by on another indexed column fast? SQL Fiddle below with schema and explains of all queries:

See [SQL Fiddle #1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed646c/1)

What's very fast so far is denormalization of search columns in a separate table and a join but I would rather not have another table if not necessary. SQL Fiddle below (denormalized query at the end):

See [SQL Fiddle #2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d6cde/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem here is something you cannot control. What is it ???

The Query Optimizer's reaction to a `FULLTEXT` index. Why ?

(Now imagine the start of a STAR WARS movie with scrolling words...)

> A very long time ago, I discovered that `FULLTEXT` indexes will nullify the MySQL Query Optimizer's use of other indexes

- `Jun 10, 2011` : [Mysql fulltext boolean ignore phrase](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3254/mysql-fulltext-boolean-ignore-phrase/3257#3257)
- `Oct 25, 2011` : [FULLTEXT index ignored in BOOLEAN MODE with 'number of words' conditional](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7136/fulltext-index-ignored-in-boolean-mode-with-number-of-words-conditional/7216#7216)
- `Mar 18, 2012` : [Why is LIKE more than 4x faster than MATCH...AGAINST on a FULLTEXT index in MySQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15214/why-is-like-more-than-4x-faster-than-match-against-on-a-fulltext-index-in-mysq/15218#15218)
- [AND MORE LIKE IT !!!](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A877%20FULLTEXT%20query%20optimizer)

## SUGGESTION

Refactor the Query so that the `MATCH ...AGAINST` collects keys only

### EXAMPLE #1

```
SELECT a.id FROM a 
WHERE
MATCH (`search1`,`search2`) AGAINST ('aaaa' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY a.id DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

should become something like

```
SELECT N.id FROM
(SELECT id FROM a WHERE
MATCH (`search1`,`search2`) AGAINST ('aaaa' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) M
INNER JOIN a N USING (id)
ORDER BY N.id DESC LIMIT 5;
```

### EXAMPLE #2

```
SELECT a.id,a.popularity FROM a 
WHERE
MATCH (`search1`,`search2`) AGAINST ('aaaa' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY a.popularity DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

should become something like

```
SELECT N.id,N.popularity FROM
(SELECT id FROM a WHERE
MATCH (`search1`,`search2`) AGAINST ('aaaa' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) M
INNER JOIN a N USING (id)
ORDER BY N.popularity DESC LIMIT 5;
```

## CONCLUSION

The main idea: Collect the keys using `MATCH ...AGAINST` and join it back to the source table

Comment: This suggestion made my query much slower.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem and found a convenient solution - at least for my tasks.

If you always have the same `ORDER BY` eg `popularity` or whatever and don't do frequent updates, eg if it's enough on a daily basis, an idea is to set up a cronjob which resorts the table every night.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ORDER BY my_sort_column ASC/DESC
```

This way you get the sorted results without filesort and any `ORDER BY` clause in the query. For my taks it took down query time from about 0.5-0.9 sec to ~0.004 for certain queries. The nightly ALTER query takes about 5-7sec on a 250k table and 11 year old Dell server.